# How to get linux `time` (real, user, sys) for current process in CPP?

Tags: c++

I'm looking to calculate elapsed real, user , sys time similar to the linux `time` cmd:

```
time [WHAT-EVER-COMMAND]
real    7m2.444s
user    76m14.607s
sys 2m29.432s
```

In cpp, to calculate the elapsed real, user and sys time between a given block of code. WE can assume this is non-portable, an a linux/posix supported system.
Which timer functions (CPP11+) can be used for this?
I've evaluated boost, chrono, ctime, time but could not find the user/sys split anywhere.
How can I grab the above data in CPP?

`<sys/times.h> times(` returns data with resolution of clock ticks, which can be retrieved with `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` and is only 100, meaning the resolution of time from `times` is 10ms.

I am looking for atleast `1ms` resolution as reported by the linux `time`. Are there any other interfaces/timers that offer better resolution for this time?

Comment: It's this command: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/times.2.html

Comment: @Homer512 the resolution on that is only 10ms, which seems very coarse. Any ideas on higher resolution calls?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, `getrusage` is the call that gets user and system time for a process (along with a bunch of other data).  See `man getrusage` for details:

```
NAME
       getrusage - get resource usage

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/time.h>
       #include <sys/resource.h>

       int getrusage(int who, struct rusage *usage);

DESCRIPTION
       getrusage() returns resource usage measures for who, which can be one of the following:

       RUSAGE_SELF
              Return  resource  usage  statistics  for  the  calling process, which is the sum of
              resources used by all threads in the process.

       RUSAGE_CHILDREN
              Return resource usage statistics for all children of the calling process that  have
              terminated  and  been waited for.  These statistics will include the resources used
              by grandchildren, and further  removed  descendants,  if  all  of  the  intervening
              descendants waited on their terminated children.

       RUSAGE_THREAD (since Linux 2.6.26)
              Return  resource  usage statistics for the calling thread.  The _GNU_SOURCE feature
              test macro must be defined (before including any header file) in  order  to  obtain
              the definition of this constant from <sys/resource.h>.

       The  resource usages are returned in the structure pointed to by usage, which has the fol‐
       lowing form:

           struct rusage {
               struct timeval ru_utime; /* user CPU time used */
               struct timeval ru_stime; /* system CPU time used */
               long   ru_maxrss;        /* maximum resident set size */
               long   ru_ixrss;         /* integral shared memory size */
               long   ru_idrss;         /* integral unshared data size */
               long   ru_isrss;         /* integral unshared stack size */
               long   ru_minflt;        /* page reclaims (soft page faults) */
               long   ru_majflt;        /* page faults (hard page faults) */
               long   ru_nswap;         /* swaps */
               long   ru_inblock;       /* block input operations */
               long   ru_oublock;       /* block output operations */
               long   ru_msgsnd;        /* IPC messages sent */
               long   ru_msgrcv;        /* IPC messages received */
               long   ru_nsignals;      /* signals received */
               long   ru_nvcsw;         /* voluntary context switches */
               long   ru_nivcsw;        /* involuntary context switches */
           };
```